# Can libcu++ be included in a regular C++ project?

Tags: cuda

I have tried using <cuda/std/chrono> and <cuda/std/array> inside my C++ project, not compiled with NVCC. The reason I am not making a CUDA project is that NVCC fails to compile some of my template code.

I am getting several errors about undefined constants such as the ones below:

`error C2065: '_LInf': undeclared identifier error C3615: constexpr function 'cuda::std::__4::__libcpp_numeric_limits<long double,true>::infinity' cannot result in a constant expression`

Can libcu++ be used inside C++ projects or only CUDA projects?

I have already tried including and linking to my C++ project the headers and libraries that are automatically added to CUDA projects by Visual Studio.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, libcu++ is intended for use with nvcc only

Comment: I would imagine that it also works (or will work in the future) with the nvc++ HPC compiler (ex PGI compiler). But that is not Windows compatible. It might work in WSL.

Comment: See the [requirements](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/setup/requirements.html) page of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments into an answer:

The system requirements [page](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/setup/requirements.html) for libcu++ indicate that only NVIDIA’s toolchains (so nvcc or the HPC SDK compilers) are supported.

More generally, libcu++ is intended to implement a subset of the C++ standard library in a transparent way which allows it to be used identically in host and device code without any programmer intervention beyond include a header and respecting its namespace conventions. It stands to reason that this requires the NVIDIA toolchain to implement this magic.